# regex string that would validate specific alphanumeric format

Tags: regex

I need to validate a specific format of numbers and letters,

What would be the regex string that would check

```
nnnnnnnnnA (example 123456789A)
```

I tried

```
^[0-9]^[0-9]^[0-9]^[0-9]^[0-9]^[0-9]^[0-9]^[0-9]^[0-9]{A-Z}$
```

but it's not forcing the `9` number plus one letter

Comment: Which part or parts of that example is variable?

Comment: Please, as the regex tag tooltip explains, provide a specific language or tool that you are using.  Regex is not standardized across all languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, with regex, you can look for a set number of things in the following way:

```
\d{1,10}
```

In this case, it's looking for between 1 and 10 total digits.

You can also use a `^` to search for something at the beginning of a line, but it doesn't really make sense in your context look for "beginning-of-line then 0-9, beginning of line, then 0-9", etc. This is what your regex seems to be attempting to match and this is most likely the reason it doesn't produce anything.

Thus, your regex will probably need to look for something like this:

```
\d{9}[A-Za-z]
```

This means a string with 9 digits and a letter at the end (lowercase and uppercase depending on the implementation. In some cases you can do `[A-z]` while if you just wanted uppercase, you can do `[A-Z]`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your regular expression engine.

The most basic would be:

```
^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]$
```

but the following should work with most engine:

```
^\d{9}[A-Z]$
```